# Hibernate query and List Object

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, select, hql

I want to get an id from my table in the database, but if I try to get the id by the name, I have to save it in a list obj, so I cant use the id from the table again because its an object and not an Integer.

My Method to update the table:

```
public void updateEvent (String eventName, String beschreibung, String datum, String ort) {

    AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    configuration.configure();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    String hql = "select a.eventID from AdminToolBean a where a.name = :Name";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setParameter ("Name", eventName);
    List<AdminToolBean> results = (List<AdminToolBean>) query.list();

    System.out.println(results.get(0));
    System.out.println(results.get(1));
    System.out.println(results.get(2));

    AdminToolBean event = (AdminToolBean) session.load(AdminToolBean.class, results.get(0));

    event.setName(eventName);
    event.setBeschreibung(beschreibung);
    event.setDatum(datum);
    event.setOrt(ort);
    session.update(event);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: Will you answer control.

Comment: if so please accept/vote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need get just an id, not an object, use simple jdbc. Spring has jdbcTemplate, or iBatis/myBatis framework.